# Is it common practice for an apt-get repository to take down files (giving 404 for them) for old versions of packages?

Tags: apt, package-management

Today I ran `apt-get update` on a slightly old system but it failed due to a 404 error. Surely it worked in the past. It looks like one of the URLs that `apt-get` tried to fetch was taken down from the repository. Is this common?

For comparison, I am pretty sure [npm](https://npmjs.com) and [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) never remove old versions from their registries, no matter how old.

---

<sub>Although I really intend for this to be a broad question, the exact situation that happened to me is actually very easy to reproduce with Docker: just do `docker run --rm -it postgres:10 bash` and then `apt-get update`. [This is the 404 URL](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/stretch-pgdg/main/binary-amd64/Packages). If you're wondering, `postgres:10` is Debian 9. I've put the full apt-get output [in pastebin, here](https://pastebin.com/bFmcwKUK).</sub>

```
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [59.1 kB]
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                           
Ign:3 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg InRelease            
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [93.6 kB]
Ign:5 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg Release             
Ign:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/10 all Packages
Get:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [782 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]                  
Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main amd64 Packages        
Ign:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/10 amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main all Packages
Get:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [3,177 B]
Ign:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/10 all Packages
Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/10 amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/10 all Packages
Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/10 amd64 Packages
Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [7,080 kB]
Ign:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/10 all Packages
Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/10 amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/10 all Packages
Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/10 amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main all Packages                           
Ign:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/10 all Packages                              
Err:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main amd64 Packages                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 87.238.57.227 80]
Ign:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/10 amd64 Packages                           
Ign:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main all Packages                           
Fetched 8,135 kB in 7s (1,092 kB/s)                                                                     
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/stretch-pgdg/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 87.238.57.227 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Yes it is very common after a release goes EOL, or even EOSS.  The team or manager of the repository can set their own rules, though the site they're using can include some too  (*and some are rather lax on when they get around to this chore, so it can be days/weeks/months even years after the EOL*).  You've provided no OS/release details, only mentioning off-topic & EOL Debian 9 (see https://wiki.debian.org/LTS) nor provided any specifics, so we can't really provide more.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks, that makes sense. Actually I did specify the exact steps to reproduce, but regardless you don't need to provide much more. I was wondering if it is common and you said yes. Thanks!

Comment: FYI:  Often the *trigger* on when a repository gets dropped is the first *bug ticket* on an EOL/EOSS resource they no longer support (*email reminding them they haven't done it*); esp. if the *drop* is believed to reduce more *tickets* on something they no longer support.  Each team is unique though.  *and FYI: I ignored the off-topic EOL-Debian reference*

Comment: Voting to close as it seems the actual problem is about a third-party repo. One common tool used for managing repos, `reprepro`, only gained support for keeping multiple versions of a package [very recently](https://askubuntu.com/a/1449183/158442), so many third party repos could only support one version at a time for a long while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is very common after a release goes EOL, or even EOSS. The team or manager of the repository can set their own rules, though the site they're using can include some too (*and some are rather lax on when they get around to this chore, so it can be days/weeks/months even years after the EOL*).

FYI:  Often the *trigger* on when a repository gets dropped is the first *bug ticket* on an EOL/EOSS resource they no longer support (*email reminding them they haven't done it*); esp. if the *drop* is believed to reduce more *tickets* on something they no longer support.  Each team is unique though.

You gave no on-topic Ubuntu specific details (*only reference to resources was for an EOL Debian release*), but each team can do decide what *standards* they decide to follow, even create their own.